# Single post shows post three times

Tags: posts, single

Not sure exactly what happened, but my site shows the single post content multiple times. [Example](https://goodbooks.today/book-arts-of-isfahan-diversity-and-identity-in-seventeenth-century-persia/). Reinstalling the theme didn't help. Also, it's not happening with any other theme, only with the current one. No plugins are active. Not sure what could be the problem.

Comment: Hi Alin, can you provide some code or further details? There's no way anyone will be able to debug this with so little information.

Comment: Is it using the `single.php` template? If so, can you please post the content of that file? It seems to be repeating `<div id="primary" class="content-area">` so I wonder if you have a bad template include.